# How would you prove that $m<a,b<M$ then $|a-b|<M-m$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $M,m,a,b\in\Bbb R$. How would you prove that $m<a,b<M$ then $|a-b|<M-m$? This little question came from a part of an exercise in analysis. Of course, this is quite simple to see if we draw these points on a number line. But how can we show this rigorously and simply?

PS: By triangle inequality, we can show that $|a-b|\leq|a-m|+|m-M|+|M-b|$, but this does not show that $|a-b|<M-m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pf I:** (A super easy proof)

Note that $\begin{cases}m<a<M\\m<b<M\end{cases}$, then $a-b<M-m$, since $M-m$ is the greatest possible value minus the lowest possible value. By the same reason we also  have $b-a<M-m$.

**Pf II:**
No matter $a$ or $b$ is the bigger, since $a<M$ and $m<b$, then $-b<-m$,

Add these two expression, we have $a+(-b)<M+(-m)$, namely $a-b<M-m$.

Since the choice of $a,b$ is arbitrary, then $b-a<M-m$ also holds.

Hence no matter $|a-b|=a-b$ or $b-a$, we have $|a-b|<M-m$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$a - b < M - m$$ and $$-(M - m) = m - M < a - b$$ Hence together $$|a - b| < M-m$$ By using that $$|x| < c \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad -c < x < c$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Inequalities of real numbers like the one in your question follow easily from the properties of order relations of real numbers, but they are not obvious / self evident unless visualized on the number line. Also note that using number line is rigorous enough because of the assumption that *to each point on the number line corresponds a unique real number and vice versa and the linear order from left to right on the number line is equivalent to the ordering of real numbers.*

But in case you wish to avoid the number line here is a simple argument. Without any loss of generality we can assume $a<b$ because the case $a=b$ is trivial and the case $a>b$ can be obtained by reversing the roles of $a, b$. We then have $$m<a<b<M$$ and clearly $$M-m=(M-b) + b -  a + (a-m) $$ The terms in parentheses on the right side of the above equation are positive and hence $M-m>b-a=|a-b|$. The technique of splitting an expression into multiple terms by adding and subtracting the same quantity is heavily used in analysis mainly to establish inequalities like these.